# Why is my jasmine test failing on my AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm getting this error:

"Controller: MainCtrl should retrieve a list of users and assign to scope.users FAILED
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Users.findAll()')
        at /Users/John/NetBeansProjects/ClearsoftDemo/app/scripts/controllers.js:21
        at invoke (/Users/John/NetBeansProjects/ClearsoftDemo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869)"

Here is the controller code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Users) {
        $scope.users = Users.findAll();
        $scope.sortField = 'lastName';
        $scope.reverseSort = true;
    })
```

Here is the service code:

```
service.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:8080/ClearsoftDemoBackend/webresources/clearsoft.demo.users', {}, {
    findAll: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
});
```

});

And here is the test code:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    var users = {query: function () {
            return [{}];
        }};
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        Users: users
    });
}));
```

Comment: Your `Users` in test does not define a `findAll`, but just a `query`

Comment: Thanks Luis.  If you officially answer my question using the "Answer" button i can mark it correct so you get credit.

Comment: Also, note that you've declared a `Users` service, so you don't need to make a mock version of it in the test. You can make the test suite aware of the service by using a `beforeEach()`:  `beforeEach(module('name.of.module.with.service'));` (put the names of any modules that you rely on in the test as String arguments to this function)

Comment: Thanks Sunil.  I was told that it is better to mock the services for unit testing of the controller and that services should be tested in a different unit test.  The idea was that one will have few dependency issues and better separation of concerns.  What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the problem: Your mock does not declare the `findAll` method. Note that your `Users` resource declares `findAll` as an additional method - your much should too.

Comment: Luis:  I was told that it is better to mock the services for unit testing of the controller and that services should be tested in a different unit test.  The idea was that one will have few dependency issues and better separation of concerns.  What do you think about that?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right. I thought about integration tests xD.